# How do I add a contact to a phonebook program in C?

Tags: c

For my intro to programming class, we have to code a phonebook in C that lets users add contacts, as well as delete and display them. It also has to allocate and free memory as necessary (I tried to do this, but I honestly don't really know what I'm doing).

Anyway, I cannot figure out how to add a contact to the phonebook. I've pasted the relevant part of the program so far. It compiles, but it crashes every time I try to add a contact. Once I get this figured out, I think I can get the rest of the functions without too much trouble. If anyone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct entry {
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
    char pnumber[20];
} entry;

// function prototypes
void addentry(int, entry*, char addfname[20], char addlname[20], char addpnumber[20]);

main() {
    int selection = 0;
    int inputtest = 1;
    int pnum = 0; // keeps track of number of contacts

    char addfname[20] = { '\0' };
    char addlname[20] = { '\0' };
    char addpnumber[20] = { '\0' };

    entry *pcontacts;
    pcontacts = (entry*)calloc(1, (sizeof(entry)));

    if (pcontacts == NULL) {
        printf("No memory is available.");
        free(pcontacts);
        return 0;
    }

    while (1) {
        do {
            printf("\nPhonebook Menu\n\n");
            printf("1:\tAdd contact\n");
            printf("2:\tDelete contact\n");
            printf("3:\tDisplay contacts\n");
            printf("4:\tExit\n");
            printf("\nChoose an action (1-4): ");
            scanf("%d", &selection);

            if (selection < 1 || selection > 4) {
                printf("Invalid input. Please enter an integer between 1 and 4.\n");
                inputtest = 0;
            }
            if (selection == 4) {
                free(pcontacts);
                printf("\nThank you for using this phonebook.");
                return 0;
            }
            switch (selection) {
              case 1:
                pnum++;
                printf("\nEnter first name: ");
                scanf("%s", addfname);
                printf("Enter last name: ");
                scanf("%s", addlname);
                printf("Enter phone number (no spaces): ");
                scanf("%s", addpnumber);
                addentry(pnum, pcontacts, addfname[20], addlname[20], addpnumber[20]);
                break;
            }   
        } while (inputtest == 1);   
    }
}

void addentry(int pnum, entry *pcontacts, char addfname[20], char addlname[20], char pnumber[20]) { 

     pcontacts = (entry*)malloc(pnum * (sizeof(entry)));

     if (pcontacts != NULL) {
         strcpy(*pcontacts[pnum - 1].fname, addfname);
         printf("\nContact has been added.");
     } else {
         printf ("No memory is available.\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: use a debugger to find out where the crash takes place.

Comment: In C function args are passed by value. So `pcontacts = (entry*)malloc(pnum * (sizeof(entry)));` only sets a *local* variable and is lost as soon as the function exits. That is, that function is in effect a big noop. And it doesn't make sense to allocate `pnum` entries, fill in the last entry and then leave everything else before it uninitialised. Clearly you need to *add* to an existing list/array/data structure and not do what you are doing.

Comment: `strcpy(*pcontacts[pnum-1].fname, addfname);`. That's the line that may be causing your crash (apart from being functionally wrong as described above). It should be `strcpy(pcontacts[pnum-1].fname, addfname);`

Comment: I question indexing using `[pnum-1]` which can be very bad if `pnum==0`. In this case, you incremented the number of records before processing a new entry, subsequently having to decrement it to use as index. It's cack-handed. Far better to increment the number of records *after* the processing is done. If you start with 0 records, then 0 is the index you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get strings from standard input with `scanf`, but you should tell `scanf` the maximum number of bytes to store to the destination arrays to avoid buffer overruns:

```
scanf("%19s", addfname);
...
scanf("%19s", addlname);
...
scanf("%19s", addpnumber);
```

The way you call `addentry` is incorrect:

```
addentry(pnum, pcontacts, addfname[20], addlname[20], addpnumber[20]);
```

You actually try to read the byte just after the end of `addfname`, `addlname` and `addpnumber`.  You should instead pass the arrays themselves, that will be passed to the function `addentry` as pointers to their first bytes:

```
addentry(pnum, pcontacts, addfname, addlname, addpnumber);
```

`addentry` should reallocate the array with `realloc`.  It should be passed a pointer to the array pointer to it can update the pointer in `main`.

`addentry` does not copy the strings correctly: it only copies one, but with a syntax error.

Here is a corrected version:

```
void addentry(int, entry**, char addfname[20], char addlname[20], char addpnumber[20]);

int main(void) {
    int selection = 0;
    int inputtest = 1;
    int pnum = 0; // keeps track of number of contacts

    char addfname[20];
    char addlname[20];
    char addpnumber[20];

    entry *pcontacts = NULL;

    for (;;) {
        do {
            printf("\nPhonebook Menu\n\n");
            printf("1:\tAdd contact\n");
            printf("2:\tDelete contact\n");
            printf("3:\tDisplay contacts\n");
            printf("4:\tExit\n");
            printf("\nChoose an action (1-4): ");
            scanf("%d", &selection);

            if (selection < 1 || selection > 4) {
                printf("Invalid input. Please enter an integer between 1 and 4.\n");
                inputtest = 0;
            }
            if (selection == 4) {
                free(pcontacts);  /* OK for NULL */
                printf("\nThank you for using this phonebook.");
                return 0;
            }
            switch (selection) {
              case 1:
                printf("\nEnter first name: ");
                scanf("%19s", addfname);
                printf("Enter last name: ");
                scanf("%19s", addlname);
                printf("Enter phone number (no spaces): ");
                scanf("%19s", addpnumber);
                addentry(pnum, &pcontacts, addfname, addlname, addpnumber);
                pnum++;
                break;
            }   
        } while (inputtest == 1);   
    }
}

/* add an entry at position pnum */
void addentry(int pnum, entry **pp, char addfname[20], char addlname[20], char pnumber[20]) {

     entry *pcontact = *pp;
     pcontacts = realloc(pcontacts, (pnum + 1) * sizeof(entry));

     if (pcontacts != NULL) {
         *pp = pcontacts; /* update pointer in main */
         strcpy(pcontacts[pnum].fname, addfname);
         strcpy(pcontacts[pnum].lname, addlname);
         strcpy(pcontacts[pnum].pnumber, addpnumber);
         printf("\nContact has been added.");
     } else {
         printf ("No memory is available.\n");
     }
}
```